# Is Searing Arrows affected by Strafe?

Tags: dota-2

If I use [Clinckz](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Clinkz)'s Strafe ability, which `dramatically increases attack speed for a short time`, can I cast Searing Arrows faster? Or Strafe only affects the normal attack?

Comment: Yes you can cast Searing arrows faster assuming it is A)on autocast, B)Not being overridden by a different orb effect and C) nothing I just mentioned has changed from dota 1 to dota 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Searing Arrows is what's called a Unique Attack Modifier (or more commonly, an Orb Effect). Orb Effects just override your original attack with the same characteristics of a typical attack (attack speed, damage, attack point, backswing, etc.) plus whatever bonus the orb gives.

Other examples are Enchantress's Impetus, Silencer's Glaives, OD's Astral Orb, etc.

Comment: As of 6.82 Searing Arrows is no longer a Unique Attack Modifier. (It's still an orb effect though.)